# Перебор всех комбинаций элементов из заданных n множеств

Tags: java, c++, алгоритм, комбинаторика, множества

Как можно сгенерировать все возможные комбинации, состоящие из элементов заданных n множеств ? Например, если имеется 3 множества:

```
A=1,2,3,4,...
B=a,b,c,d,...
C=A,B,C,D,...
```

и нужно получить что-то вроде:

```
1 a A; 
1 b A; 
1 c A
....
1 a B; 
1 b B
```

При этом число `n` заранее неизвестно, так что вложенными циклами решить не получается.

Comment: также можно загуглить реализацию "cartesian product" для вашего языка программирования

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Представьте себе, что это - цифры, стоящие на соответствующих местах числа.

Создаем первое число - `1aA` (или сколько там нужно мест). Потом просто увеличиваем последний элемент, пока не переберем все. После этого выставляем его равным минимальному элементу и увеличиваем предыдущий (если он тоже максимален - сбрасываем его в минимум и переходим к предыдущему).

```
1aA
1aB
1aC  // достигли максимума в последней позиции. переход-
1bA
1bB
1bC  // достигли максимума в последней позиции. переход-
1bA
1bB
1bC  // достигли максимума в последней позиции. переход-
1bA
1bB
1bC  // достигли максимума в последней позиции. переход-
1сA
1сB
1сC  // достигли максимума в последней позиции. переход- но во второй позиции
     // тоже максимум, перенос далее
2aA
...
```

Словом, просто реализуем алгоритм M (*Генерация в смешанной позиционной системе счисления*) со страницы 330 4А тома "Искусства программирования"...